# Use two GET parameters in single url

Tags: php

I have a code that opens external images in my webpage by image ID.

> http://i.imgur.com/**dkqiQyB**.jpg

above image open by ID in my page.

> localhost.com/imgur.php?id=dkqiQyB

But I have two diffrent IDs in same URL. The bold parts below change with the image.

> http://**s7**.postimg.org/**msriw5k5n/dkqi_Qy_B**.jpg

Can we use two IDs in the same URL? How?

```
$curl = curl_init('http://i.imgur.com/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: `"http://s7.postimg.org/$_GET[id1]/$_GET[id2].jpg"`

Comment: s7 is change everytime and msriw5k5n/dkqi_Qy_B is combine. then what to type in address bar to open image? localhost.com/imgur.php?id=

Comment: `?id1=something&id2=somethingelse`

Comment: i did as you said but not working. http://dweapons.hostyd.com/test.php?id1=s7&id2=msriw5k5n/dkqi_Qy_B   . image is not open. i make change in my php code is  <?php
$curl = curl_init('http://'.$_GET['id1'].'.postimg.org/'.$_GET['id2'].'.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_exec($curl);
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl = curl_init('http://'.$_GET['s'].'.postimg.org/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

`localhost.com/image.php?s=<server>&id=<id>`

Where `<server>` is `s7` and `<id>` is `msriw5k5n/dkqi_Qy_B`

**Edit:** [small tutorial on W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)

Comment: That is not the W3C. That is W3Schools, a horrible reference if there ever was one.

Comment: @minitech If it's horrible, don't say it but give better

Comment: No, I’m scared to even click on the link to find out what it is.

Comment: @minitech I even don't understand you. Question was how to pass 2 get params. I answered and gave a link where get parameters in php are clearly explained (in form examples)